# 3 duplicated symbols in PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, editor

Other languages are fine except PHP.

How to fix this?

[Installed Extensions](https://gist.github.com/KSXGitHub/10a56240914eba347cdf1c61677f6cab)

[image: VS Code Screenshot]

Comment: This question is offtopic.

Comment: Questioner and ansner both same :))))

Comment: @Rits because I just figured it out, so I answer my own question

Comment: @Andreas Wow! You are really "helpful"!

Comment: yeah but you can edit your answer and put [solved] in your title,
with details of solution in your question.

Comment: Ok. Let me be more clear. This question does not belong here on SO and should be deleted. Either by yourself, by delete votes or mods. You pick. But the question has no value what so ever on SO. SO is for programming problems not software issues. Go to superuser or something like that with this question.

Comment: @Andreas Just your opinion! I saw people asking editor related question all the time, proof: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sublime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Andreas "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: You forgot "and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Fail.

Comment: I removed SOLVED from the title. There's no need to add that. Accepting an answer automatically marks it as such.

Comment: *"yeah but you can edit your answer and put [solved] in your title"* - @Rits Please don't suggest that, it isn't how things are done here on Stack.

Comment: Okay sir... thanks

Answer (score -1):

I solved this. Just disable some extensions